# emacs indentation inconsistent in nesed loops

Tags: emacs, indentation

I am working on C code.

I have a problem same as that in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136090/emacs-indentation-for-multi-level-nesting-of-c-code).

The solution there is to use spaces instead of tabs. But I'm trying/I'd prefer to use [Smart Tabs Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs).

I've tried enabling and disabling both "c-tab-always-indent" and "indent-tabs-mode" (in cc-mode-hook).

The problem I see is that in some parts of the code a nested loop generates two Tabs, as expected(?). But in some cases, it generates only one tab and four spaces, while in other cases it generates only one tab, something like below:

```
function_name
open brace here
...code indented by 4 spaces (though I want a tab)>
 open_brace
_tab_  code under condition
_4spc_ close_brace
some more 4 space aligned code
_tab_  open_brace
_tab+4spc_ code under some block
_tab_  close_brace
some more 4 space aligned code
_tab_ open_brace
_2 tabs_ code aligned as I prefer with two tabs
_tab_ close_brace
```

Can someone help me with getting the last style in the whole code?

My .emacs file is here (I use a few packages, like cscope and hide-show, but I don't think that should cause problems):

```
    (custom-set-variables
     ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
     ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
     ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
     ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
     '(ansi-color-faces-vector [default default default italic underline success warning error])
     '(ansi-color-names-vector ["black" "red3" "ForestGreen" "yellow3" "blue" "magenta3" "DeepSkyBlue" "gray50"])
     '(c-basic-offset 4)
     '(c-cleanup-list (quote (scope-operator space-before-funcall compact-empty-funcall)))
     '(c-default-style (quote ((c-mode . "linux") (c++-mode . "linux") (java-mode . "java") (awk-mode . "awk") (other . "gnu"))))
     '(c-hanging-braces-alist (quote set-from-style))
    ; '(c-tab-always-indent t)
     '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tango-dark)))
     '(save-place t nil (saveplace))
     '(show-paren-mode t))
    (custom-set-faces
     ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
     ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
     ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
     ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
     )

    (setq savehist-additional-variables    ;; also save...
      '(search-ring regexp-search-ring)    ;; ... my search entries
      savehist-file "~/.emacs.d/savehist") ;; keep my home clean

    (defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p) ; to answer y or n instead of yes or no :-P ...I'm to lazy
    (setq search-highlight t            ;; highlight when searching... 
          query-replace-highlight 1)        ;; ...and replacing

    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/packages/")
    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/share/emacs/site-lisp")


    ;;;add packages
    ;;(require 'doxymacs)

    ;;; turn ons
    (ido-mode) 
    (savehist-mode 1)
    (setq show-paren-mode 1)
    (global-linum-mode 1)
    (setq column-number-mode 1)


    ;;cc-mode changes
    (require 'smart-tabs-mode)
    (require 'xcscope)
    (cscope-setup)

    (autoload 'smart-tabs-mode "smart-tabs-mode"
      "Intelligently indent with tabs, align with spaces!")
    (autoload 'smart-tabs-mode-enable "smart-tabs-mode")
    (autoload 'smart-tabs-advice "smart-tabs-mode")
    (autoload 'smart-tabs-insinuate "smart-tabs-mode")

    (defun my-c-mode-common-hook ()
      (setq require-trailing-newline 1)   ;; Always add a final newline
      (which-function-mode 1)
      (subword-mode 1)
      (hs-minor-mode 1)  
      (setq show-paren-style 'parenthesis)
    ;  (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
      (smart-tabs-mode 1)
      )

    (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-mode-common-hook)
```

Comment: Would setting `tab-width` to 4 help?

Comment: That's already set in cc mode.

Comment: Not sure if it will help, but anyway:
did you set c-basic-offset to 4?
what is your "tab-stop-list"?

Comment: I'll edit the question, and put in my .emacs here. Sorry, for the slip on that count.

Comment: @lgfang To answer your question: c-basic-offset is set to 4. As I mentioned, I think the problem is more to do with whether a tab or two tabs or tabs and spaces are being used - and I couldn't figure out, which is used when.